# Is it possible to pass a function's value into a component in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I have an app that displays Users and I want to show additional information whenever I press a user.

```js
class DetailsUsersScreen extends Component  {
    constructor(){
    super()
      this.state = {
      users:[]
      };

    expandDetail = () => {
        this.setState(previousState => ({ content: !previousState.content}))}
        
    getUsers = async() => {
      const res = await Http.instance.get("random link which retrieves a set of users")
      this.setState({users:res, allClients:res})
  
    getUserId = (item) => {
      const userInfo = item
      return userInfo
    
  }
    render() {
    
    const {users} = this.state
    
      return (
      
      <View>
                {this.state.content ?
              <View style={{shadowOffset: {
                                width: 0,
                                height: 3,
                              },
                              marginTop: 20,
                              backgroundColor:'#48555D',
                              shadowOpacity: 0.7,
                              shadowRadius: 4.65,
                              elevation: 3,
                              paddingTop: 10,
                              paddingHorizontal: 10,
                              borderRadius: 5
                              }}>
                <View  style={{flex: 0.8, flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', margin:10, justifyContent: 'space-between', backgroundColor:'green' }}>
                  <Text style={styles.titleText}>Today </Text>
                  <Image source={require('../../assets/download.png')} />
                </View>
                <View style={{paddingTop:30}}>
                <FlatList
                  data={users}
                  renderItem={({item}) => (
                    <TouchableHighlight activeOpacity={0.9} underlayColor="#7a7a7a" onPress={()=>{this.expandDetail(),this.getUserId(item)}}>
                      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', justifyContent: 'space-between', paddingBottom: 15}}>
                        <View>
                          <Text style={styles.nIdentifyText}>{item.metadata.fingerid}</Text>
                          <Text style={styles.nameText}>{item.name}</Text>
                          <Text style={styles.emailText}>{item.email}</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View>
                          <Text style={styles.typeText}>{item.type}</Text>
                          <Text style={styles.emailText}>{item.fecha}</Text>
                          <Text style={styles.dateText}>{item.datetime}</Text>

                        </View>
                      </View>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                  )
                
                }
                /> 
          
                </View>
                
              </View>:<UserDetailExpanded>
          </UserDetailExpanded>}
      )
    }
 }
```

This code shows the users i get from an URL. Notice that I'm also using a method in which I hide the entire flatlist once I press a user, that's where the line "{this.state.content ?..." comes in. The component `<UserDetailExpanded/>` at the end of the code is the component I want to show once I hide the entire flatlist in which shows me additional information regarding the user i just Clicked. Its content are for now:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, Button } from "react-native"

class UserDetailExpanded extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Hello World</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default UserDetailExpanded;
```

My logic is this: once I press a user from a Flatlist, I execute a function called `expandDetail()` which hides the entire flatlist. Once it hides, I also execute a function bound to when I press a user that retrieves a user's data, which is `getUserId()` and I want to pass that data to a component at the end named `<UserDetailExpanded/>` and show the information inside the component. Is there a way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to do this with a navigation library like react-navigation that way users will be able to back press to get back to the list, but lets say you want to do this all on one screen.

It would also in general be simpler as a functional component but lets keep it a class.

start by adding a state variable called selectedUser: null

render becomes

```
render (){
const { users, selectedUser } = this.state
if(!selectedUserId) return <UserDetailExpanded user={selectedUser} />
return (
 // this is where your current flatlist goes
)
```

}

then your onPress in your flatlist should look like this

```
onPress={() => this.setState({ ...state, selectedUser: item )}
```

then in your UserDetailExpanded component you can access everything in user you can see this by adding some logs so change it to this

```
class UserDetailExpanded extends Component {
    console.log(this.props.user)
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Hello World</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }

}
```

finally if you want to be able to return to the UserDetailExplained component you can create a function inside DetailsUsersScreen that looks like this

goBackToList() {
this.setState({ ...state, selectedUser: null )}
}

then in the constructor you must add

```
this.goBackToList = this.goBackToList.bind(this);
```

then you can update

```
<UserDetailExpanded user={selectedUser} />
```

to

```
<UserDetailExpanded user={selectedUser} goBack={goBackToList} />
```

and then inside your UserDetailExpanded you can add a button that has an onPress that looks like this

```
onPress={this.props.goBack}
```